Upgrade Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 170614) to 10.4
What is the best approach Upgrade Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 170614) to 10.4 and SC 8.2 using Mongo DB.  Is below approach is Correct?

SC 8.2 -> 10.0.1 (migrate Mongo DB collection to SQL tables) , after upgrade no Mongo DB
SC 10.0.1 --> 10.4


Your approach seems mostly correct. Here's a detailed breakdown of the steps you need to follow.

Upgrade from Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 170614) to 10.0.1

You will need to migrate the data stored in MongoDB (contacts, interactions) to SQL. This involves:

Exporting MongoDB data.
Using the xDB Data Migration Tool (provided by Sitecore) to import the MongoDB collections (like contacts, interactions) into SQL databases such as the xDB Collection database.
After this step, MongoDB is no longer required.


Once the MongoDB migration is complete and you're on Sitecore 10.0.1, you can proceed with a regular upgrade to 10.4. This involves updating the databases, files, and configurations according to the upgrade guides provided by Sitecore.


Refer to this link for upgrade guides.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/installation-and-upgrade-guides#heading-sitecore-experience-platform
Hope this helps.

There are following approaches you can use to migrate from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10.4.

In case you do not want to keep the xDB Data, you can directly migrate from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10.4.

If you want to keep your xDB data, you must first upgrade to Sitecore XP 10.0.1 and then use
the xDB Data Migration Tool to migrate your data. After you have migrated your xDB data to
Sitecore XP 10.0.1, you can upgrade to the latest Sitecore XP.


You can find more details on the below upgrade guide by Sitecore.
https://scdp.blob.core.windows.net/downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/104/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%20104/Upgrade_Installation_Guide_for_Sitecore_Experience_Platform_10_4_0.pdf
Hope this helps!!!
